# What does this function do reacjs

Tags: reactjs

This code is come from FB ReactNative Movies Demo

```
function getTextFromScore(score: number): string {
  return score > 0 ? score + '%' : 'N/A';
}
```

what is means ": string" , is return a string ?

Comment: That's the ternary operator. `x =  cond ? 1 : 2 ` is short for `if (cond) { x = 1; } else { x = 2; }`

Answer (score 2):

This syntax is for the [flow type checker](http://flowtype.org/).  In the argument list you have `(score: number)` which means the first argument of the function must be a number.  After the argument list is the return value of the function.  Which is declared as a string.

```
function getTextFromScore(score: number): string {
  return score > 0 ? score + '%' : 'N/A';
}

var x: string = getTextFromScore(5);
```

Flow is pretty smart, though, so we could remove most of these annotations.

```
// in no situation will this function not return a string
function getTextFromScore(score: number) {
  return score > 0 ? score + '%' : 'N/A';
}

// thus, in no situation will x not be a string
var x = getTextFromScore(5);
```

I like to type the arguments and return value of a function, but usually not the variables unless I think it adds something, either technically or for readability.

Answer (score 0):

It means the function returns a string.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this means this method will return a string value..
if score is greater then 0 return value by concatenating % with it or return 'NA' when value is less then or equal to 0

Answer (score 0):

```
function getTextFromScore(score: number): string {
  return score > 0 ? score + '%' : 'N/A';
}
```

function takes score of type number and returns a string
then

```
if(score > 0 ){score + '%' }else{'N/A'}
```